# how to make codeigniter uri case insensitive?

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, case-insensitive

I have url like `http://example.com/user`. I used **Codeigniter** framework to build website. My script is work fine in localhost. But after uploaded to web server it shows 404 error message.

If I user `http://example.com/User` then it work fine.

How can I changed url **case-insensitive** ????

I changed `$uri = strtolower($this->_parse_request_uri());` in `system.core/URI.php` file. But still cannot find any solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to your `routes.php` file:

```
$route['User'] = "user";
```

This will redirect users from `User` to `user`.